# changing mobile backup file location

Tags: backup, iphone, itunes-11

Is it possible in iTunes 11 to set the destination of Mobile/Backup? There isn't a pref for it in app... I have my Itunes library on a FW disk that travels with me, I'd like to have my iPhone backup on same drive.

Also I get error msg from iTunes "Not enough room..." when my laptop MBP free space is ~35GB and I attempt to backup my 4S 32GB phone. My backup folder is only 6GB (one backup) and my phone indicates ~16GB of used space ...???

Comment: am I the only one who thinks this is utterly pathetic on Apple's part not to allow me to change the location. With 128GB phones and 256GB laptop SSDS why do they still have their head in the sand on this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article that could help you, it shows how to create another folder for your backup on an external drive, if you're using a Mac: http://www.iclarified.com/28429/how-to-change-the-location-of-your-itunes-iphone-backups-mac